# Auto populate the text field with value got from a function in activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want a text View with edit text which gets a default value when focused on it. Lets say I have a text field of stock price. I have a method like below in my GetPriceActiviy:

```
public int getStockPrice() {
    ......
    //scans through online db to get current stock price and return it.  
    return price;
}
```

When an user focus on edittext for this they get a default value returned from the getStockPrice which they can modify to give a different price(a future or desired price different from current) .

Any idea to implement this will help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setText method.

If you have an EditText object, say stockPrice you can use it as follows.

```
stockPrice.setText(getStockPrice()+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onFocusChangeListener for you EditText like

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                //edittext is focused set text here
                edittext.setText(getStockPrice()+"");
            }else{
                //do nothing
            }

        }
    });
```